# Admin Dashboard - Create New Theme

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml, theme, admin-panel

I try to install a simple module for my admin dashboard but no result.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Azerty_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Azerty_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I wish my theme here: **www\app\design\adminhtml\mytheme\default**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>MyTheme</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <name>default</name>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I have forgot to specify the module. Now I have an error : **Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in www\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php on line 104** I just wish this structure: **www\app\design\adminhtml\mytheme\default\layout**
**www\app\design\adminhtml\mytheme\default\template** I use magento 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have do some mistake:

### 1. define module config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Azerty_Adminhtml>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Azerty_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>MyTheme</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <name>default</name>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

This code  should be  contain of ***`config.xml`***.Which should located at 
**`app/code/local/Azerty/Adminhtml/etc`**

### 2.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Azerty_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Azerty_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

--
It is module  main configuration file which located ***app/etc/modules/***

and file name is ***`Azerty_Adminhtml.xml`***